# How do I add service reference with multiple services - code generation error

Tags: c#, wcf, service, reference

I'm trying to add [this](https://service100.emedny.org:9047/MHService?wsdl) service reference:
But receive error messages like this:

> Custom tool error: The global type ('ActClassDocument') has been
>   defined in both
>   'https://service100.emedny.org:9047/MHService.xsd7.xsd' and
>   'https://service100.emedny.org:9047/MHService.xsd14.xsd'.

They are different at `'./union/@memberTypes'\ServiceReference1\Reference.svcmap`

What can it be?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem referencing two services that share types. In my case the solution was that the offending type (ActClassDocument in your case) was defined in two places within the same namespace, but with different fields (either a field type on the two classes were different or extra non-optional fields are specified on one of them). Check the definitions of 'ActClassDocument' on both XSD files and make sure they can translate to the same .NET interface.

On my side the problem was solved on the service side. We have service A and B, both referencing types in XSD X. A change was made to the XSD, but only service A was updated which resulted in service A and B's definition being different. The person responsible for the service had to refresh B with the latest XSD and my service reference update worked.